# how I'm gonna create the URL pattern for each topic?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, url

I want to create a URL patterns for each topic. How I'm gonna do that??
This is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add_task/', views.add_task, name='add_task'),
]
```

**forms.py**
from django import forms
from .models import Task

```
    class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
        title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'add new 
        task...'}))

        class Meta:
            model = Task
            fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm


def index(request):
    task = Task.objects.all()
    context = {'task': task}
    return render(request, 'my_app/index.html', context)


def add_task(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TaskForm()
    else:
        form = TaskForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('my_app:index')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'my_app/add_task.html', context)
```

**base.html**

## To do

```
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

**index.html**
{% extends 'my_app/base.html' %}

```
    {% block content %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'my_app:add_task' %}">Add task</a></p>
    <ul>
        {% for tasks in task %}
        <li>
            {{ tasks }}
        </li>

        {% empty %}
        <li>
            <p>There's no task</p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

**add_task.html**
{% extends 'my_app/base.html' %}

```
    {% block content %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'my_app:index' %}">Index</a></p>
    <p>Add task</p>
    <a href="{% url 'my_app:task' task.id%}">{{ tasks }}}</a>
    <form action="{% url 'my_app:add_task' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}
        <button type="submit">Add task</button>

    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

So I want to create a To do app. I created a form but know I want to create URL patterns for each topic. How I'm gonna do that??

Comment: Do you want to create a URL pattern for each task created?

Comment: Yes I want to create URL pattern for each task created

Comment: Ok I wrote a full answer below

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a URL for each task in your database would be using `<pk>` in a url. Django allows you to pass items in your urls that you can get in your views. Here's what you could do:
in URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add_task/', views.add_task, name='add_task'),
    path('task-details/<pk>', views.task_detail_view, name='task_detail'),
]
```

Then in your view, you can get the pk doing this:

```
def task_detail_view(request, **kwargs):
    task_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_pk)
    # Perform more logic and render html page...
```

Then if you wanted to create a link to this page in another html page, you can do something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_app:task_detail' <pk> %}">link</a>
```

`<pk>` would be an integer representing the pk of the task you wanted to link to. In your case in 'index.html', you would probably want to put 'tasks.pk' in this spot instead of ''